# RegEx for extracting data (aggregate) from raw text / table

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm working on a regex task where I need to create a regular expression to identify within text file > table

All rows having the first column starting with `VI-` and ending with `(PP)` or `(DB)`, extract and add up the absolute values for the last column (ie 0.73 + 0.11…).

Then print the total value.

Here is the attached text file.

```regex
FEES          Amount charged to authorize, process and settle card transactions, along with transaction-based and/or fixed amounts charged for specific card processingservices.
            MC-WORLDCARD RESTAURANT                                                                                      Interchange charges                      -$13.85
            MC-CORP T & E I(US) BUS                                                                                      Interchange charges                            -$0.85
            MC-CORP T & E I(US) CORP                                                                                     Interchange charges                            -$3.18
            MC-WORLD ELITE RESTAURANT                                                                                    Interchange charges                      -$22.02
            MC-HIGH VAL RESTAURANT                                                                                       Interchange charges                            -$2.16
            MC-DOMESTIC MERIT III                                                                                        Interchange charges                            -$3.74
            MC-RESTAURANT (DB)                                                                                           Interchange charges                            -$2.22
            MC-DOMESTIC MERIT III (DB)                                                                                   Interchange charges                            -$2.03
            MASTERCARD SALES DISCOUNT .006 DISC RATE TIMES $2743.61                                                        Service charges                        -$16.46
            MC LICENSE VOLUME FEE .000061 DISC RATE TIMES $3143.14                                                         Service charges                              -$0.19
            MASTERCARD DEBIT SALES DISC .006 DISC RATE TIMES $399.53                                                       Service charges                              -$2.40
            MASTERCARD AUTH FEE 96 TRANSACTIONS AT .05                                                                          Fees                                    -$4.80
            MC NETWORK ACCESS AUTH FEE 96 TRANSACTIONS AT .0195                                                                 Fees                                    -$1.87
        VISA
            VI-US REGULATED COMM (DB)                                                                                    Interchange charges                            -$0.51
            VI-CPS SMALL TICKET (PP)                                                                                     Interchange charges                            -$0.11
            VISA ASSESSMENT FEE CR .0014 TIMES $6964.33                                                                  Interchange charges                            -$9.75
            VISA ASSESSMENT FEE DB .0013 TIMES $2168.68                                                                  Interchange charges                            -$2.82
            VI-CPS/RESTAURANT (DB)                                                                                       Interchange charges                            -$7.77
            VI-CORPORATE TRAVEL SVC                                                                                      Interchange charges                            -$2.73
            VI-CPS/RESTAURANT CREDIT                                                                                     Interchange charges                            -$7.23
            VI-PURCHASING TRAVEL SVC                                                                                     Interchange charges                            -$1.23
            VI-ELECTRONIC (US ACQ)                                                                                       Interchange charges                            -$0.46
            VI-INTER PREM LAC ISS US ACQ                                                                                 Interchange charges                            -$3.13
            VI-SIGNATURE PREFERRED CRP ELC                                                                               Interchange charges                      -$60.70
            VI-SIGNATURE CARD ELECTRONIC                                                                                 Interchange charges                      -$52.58
            VI-BUSINESS CARD TR2 ELEC T&E                                                                                Interchange charges                            -$9.21
            VI-BUSINESS CARD TR4 ELEC                                                                                    Interchange charges                            -$8.97
            VI-BUSINESS CARD CP (DB)                                                                                     Interchange charges                            -$0.54
            VI-CPS/RESTAURANT (PP)                                                                                       Interchange charges                            -$0.73
            VI-CPS/SMALL TICKET                                                                                          Interchange charges                            -$3.62
            VI-BUSINESS CARD TR1 ELEC T&E                                                                                Interchange charges                            -$6.32
            VI-BUSINESS CARD TR3 ELEC T&E                                                                                Interchange charges                            -$7.46
            VI-CPS SMALL TICKET (DB)                                                                                     Interchange charges                            -$1.12
            VI-US REGULATED (DB)                                                                                         Interchange charges                            -$7.89
            VI-CPS/REWARDS 2                                                                                             Interchange charges                      -$16.87
            VI-US HNW CONSUMER ELECT                                                                                     Interchange charges                            -$0.81
            VI-US CPS/SMALL TCKT REG (DB)                                                                                Interchange charges                            -$1.58
            VISA DEBIT SALES DISCOUNT .006 DISC RATE TIMES $2168.68                                                        Service charges                        -$13.01
            VISA SALES DISCOUNT .006 DISC RATE TIMES $6964.33                                                              Service charges                        -$41.79
            VISA AUTH FEE 280 TRANSACTIONS AT .05                                                                               Fees                              -$14.00
            ACQUIRER PROCESSOR FEE DB/PP 65 TRANSACTIONS AT .0155                                                               Fees                                    -$1.01
            ACQUIRER PROCESSOR FEE CREDIT 212 TRANSACTIONS AT .0195                                                             Fees                                    -$4.13
        DISCOVER
            DSCVR PSL REST PR                                                                                            Interchange charges                            -$4.01
            DSCVR PSL REST PP                                                                                            Interchange charges                            -$0.86
            DISCOVER ASSESSMENT FEE .0013 TIMES $960.98                                                                  Interchange charges                            -$1.25
            DSCVR COMML ELECT OTHER                                                                                      Interchange charges                            -$4.06
            DSCVR PSL EXP SVC PR                                                                                         Interchange charges                            -$0.62
            DSCVR PSL EXP SVC RW                                                                                         Interchange charges                            -$1.62
            DSCVR PSL REST RW                                                                                            Interchange charges                      -$10.91
            DISCOVER SALES DISCOUNT .006 DISC RATE TIMES $960.98                                                           Service charges                              -$5.77
            DISCOVER DATA USAGE FEE 35 TRANSACTIONS AT .0195                                                               Service charges                              -$0.68
            DISCOVER AUTH FEE 35 TRANSACTIONS AT .05                                                                            Fees                                    -$1.75
            NETWORK AUTHORIZATION FEE 35 TRANSACTIONS AT .0025                                                                  Fees                                    -$0.09
        AMERICAN EXPRESS
            AMEX AUTH FEE 17 TRANSACTIONS AT .05                                                                                Fees                                    -$0.85
```

Here is the php code.

```
<?php 
    $file = fopen("sampledata.txt", "r") or die("Cannot open file!\n"); 

    $regex = "/VI-\w.+?(\(PP\)|\(DB\))+/g"; // regex, but it selected the individual row > field. see the sreenshot.
    $total = 0;

    while ($line = fgets($file, 1024)) { 

        preg_match_all($regex, $line, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

        if (count($matches) > 0) { 

            // sum the matching value.
        } else { 
            echo "No match: "; 
        } 
    }

    fclose($file);

    print_r($total);

?>
```

Regex result

[image: Regex result]

Comment: You can't do addition with a regular expression, it's just used for matching. You need a programming language to add up the matched values. `awk` is a good language for matching a regular expression, extracting data from the matched rows, and doing calculations.

Comment: There are no numbers in any of the lines that end with `(PP)` or `(DB)`. How is it supposed to add those number?

Comment: I have updated the php code.

Comment: You need a delimiter around the regex: `$regex = "/(VI-)+\w|\(PP\)/";`

Comment: If you want to match lines beginning with `VI-` and ending with `(PP)`, you shouldn't have `|` in the regexp. That's "or", not "and".

Comment: The `+` should be *after* `\w`, not before it. I think you need to read a regular expression tutorial, you have lots of mistakes.

Comment: And you still haven't explained what you want to add, since there are no numbers on those lines.

Comment: You don't need parentheses around `VI-`.

Comment: Sorry! I had copied from regex101.com that missed the "\" I have shared the screenshot with updated regex now.

Comment: use `+?` to make it use non-greedy matching.

Comment: The `s` modifier makes it match across multiple lines. If you just want to match a single row, don't use `s`.

Comment: The `s` modifier is irrelevant in the PHP script, because you're using `fgets()`, which just reads one line at a time.

Comment: Here is the updated `/VI-\w.+?(\(PP\)|\(DB\))+/g` and it's matched the first field....Also updated the question.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you want to add. There are no numbers on the lines that match this pattern.

Comment: Maybe you want to add the number at the end of the next line?

Comment: Yes the table has three columns.... and number exists at last column....as specified in text file format.

Comment: I don't see 3 columns. I see one column on the line that matches the regexp, and two columns on the next line.

Comment: But sometimes there are two lines that match the pattern in a row, with no number line.  Like `VI-US REGULATED COMM (DB) ` followed by `VI-CPS SMALL TICKET (PP)`.

Comment: Yeah... in such case we might have to defferentiate by `\n` and consider two row.

Comment: All my above comments about the numbers not being on the same line were wrong. I didn't realize I had to scroll to the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There no needs for preg_match_all, the `g` flag is implicit with preg_match and you have to capture the value present at the end of line if you want to sum them.

Use: `/VI-.+?\((?:PP|DB)\).+?\$(\d+(?:\.\d\d)?)/`

**Explanation:**

```
/               # regex delimiter
  VI-           # literally VI-
  .+?           # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  \(            # opening parenthesis
  (?:           # non capture group
    PP|DB       # PP or DB
  )             # end group
  \)            # closing parenthesis
  .+?           # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  \$            # $ sign
  (             # start group 1
    \d+         # 1 or more digits
    (?:         # non capture group
      \.\d\d    # a dot and 2 digits
    )?          # end group, optional
  )             # end group 1
/               # regex delimiter
```

**Code:**

```
$file = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("Cannot open file!\n"); 

$regex = '/VI-.+?\((?:PP|DB)\).+?\$(\d+(?:\.\d\d)?)/'; 
$total = 0;
while ($line = fgets($file, 1024)) { 
    if (preg_match($regex, $line, $matches)) {
        $total += $matches[1];
    } 
}
fclose($file);
echo $total,"\n";
```

**Output (for given example):**

```
20.25
```